# Set title in the window popup

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to set a title in the window popup?

I have this in javascript:

```
var popup = window.open('......');
popup.document.title = "my title";
```

but this does not work..still can't see any title

EDIT: the page popup is displaying is .aspx and it HAS a title tag, but still can't see that on the popup window..

Comment: What exactly is "......"?  When you open a window to a URL, then that page will generally set the title with a `<title>` attribute in the header.  Is the URL from your domain?

Comment: it's another internal page.. So probably title tag is missing in that page, will check it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since `popup.onload` does not seem to work, here is a workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/mta5x469/.

```
var win = window.open('', 'foo', ''); // open popup

function check() {
    if(win.document) { // if loaded
        win.document.title = "test"; // set title
    } else { // if not loaded yet
        setTimeout(check, 10); // check in another 10ms
    }
}

check(); // start checking
```

Comment: this doesn't work in my case, where i have a url in window.open

Comment: This doesn't work for me, where i'm trying to open pdf file in new tab

Answer (score 5):

I was having problems with the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7501545/1037948) until I realized that if you open an existing, **slow** page that already has a `<title>` the browser will 1) set your title, then 2) once the document *fully* loads it will (re)set the popup title with the "normal" value.

So, introducing a reasonable delay (function `openPopupWithTitle`):

```
var overridePopupTitle = function(popup, title, delayFinal, delayRepeat) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/7501545/1037948
    // delay writing the title until after it's fully loaded,
    // because the webpage's actual title may take some time to appear
    if(popup.document) setTimeout(function() { popup.document.title = title; }, delayFinal || 1000);
    else setTimeout(function() { overridePopupTitle(popup, title); }, delayRepeat || 100);
}
var openPopupWithTitle = function(url, title, settings, delay) {
    var win = window.open(url, title, settings);
    overridePopupTitle(win, title, delay);
    return win;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me. I was trying to open a popup with a PDF inside and kept getting permission denied trying to set the title using the above methods. I finally found another post that pointed me in the correct direction. Below is the code I ended up using.

Source: [How to Set the Title in Window Popup When Url Points to a PDF File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135487/how-to-set-title-in-window-popup-when-url-points-to-a-pdf-file)

```
    var winLookup;
    var showToolbar = false;

    function openReportWindow(m_title, m_url, m_width, m_height)
    {
        var strURL;
        var intLeft, intTop;

        strURL = m_url;

        // Check if we've got an open window.
        if ((winLookup) && (!winLookup.closed))
            winLookup.close();

        // Set up the window so that it's centered.
        intLeft = (screen.width) ? ((screen.width - m_width) / 2) : 0;
        intTop = (screen.height) ? ((screen.height - m_height) / 2) : 0;

        // Open the window.
        winLookup = window.open('', 'winLookup','scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,toolbar='+(showToolbar?'yes':'no')+',height=' + m_height + ',width=' + m_width + ',top=' + intTop + ',left=' + intLeft);
        checkPopup(m_url, m_title);

        // Set the window opener.
        if ((document.window != null) && (!winLookup.opener))
            winLookup.opener = document.window;

        // Set the focus.
        if (winLookup.focus)            
            winLookup.focus();
    }

    function checkPopup(m_url, m_title) {     
        if(winLookup.document) { 
            winLookup.document.write('<html><head><title>' + m_title + '</title></head><body height="100%" width="100%"><embed src="' +m_url + '" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%" /></body></html>');
        } else { 
            // if not loaded yet
            setTimeout(checkPopup(m_url, m_title), 10); // check in another 10ms
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't setTimeout take a function, and you're passing the result of a checkPopup function call?

If checkPopup had no arguments, you could pass checkPopup to setTimeout.  Or you could pass "function(){checkPopup(m_url, m_title)}" to setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help,

```js
function GetInput() {
  var userInput;
  var stringOutput;
  userInput = prompt('What should the title be?', "");
  stringOutput = userInput;
  document.title = stringOutput;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="GetInput()">Change Title</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also

```
var popup = window.open('......');
popup.onload = function () {
popup.document.title = "my title";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var win= window.open('......');
win.document.writeln("<title>"+yourtitle+"</title>");
```

This works for me, tested in chromium browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a setTitle method in my popup window and calling it from my parent page.

```
//popup page:
function setTitle(t) {
    document.title = t;
}

//parent page
popupWindow.setTitle('my title');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it will work.

```
var timerObj, newWindow;

function openDetailsPopUpWindow(url) {
    newWindow = window.open(url, '', 'height=500,width=700,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    timerObj = window.setInterval("fun_To_ReTitle('~~newTitle~~ ')", 10);
}


function fun_To_ReTitle(newTitle){
    if (newWindow.document.readyState == 'complete') {
        newWindow.document.title=newTitle;
        window.clearInterval(timerObj);
    }
}
```