# how to set the browser title from popup window title

Tags: javascript

im working on Poetry website and i will show the poems on popup window
how to set the browser title as the popup title , to make the social media share button grab the poem title NOT the browser title

```
<div class="popup">
<h2>popup title</h2>
<p>content</p>
<a class="close" href="#close"></a>
</div>
<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="poem4_form"></a>
```

Comment: I think you should solve this issue by looking at the different social media api and find out how to change the title of the shared link instead of changing the window title.

Comment: Facebook disabled this feature

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.title = window.opener.document.title
```

Alternative you can do:

```
var win = window.open('', 'foo', '');

//Ensure, the Document is loaded
function check() {        
    if(win.document) {
        //Set Title
        win.document.title = document.title
    } else {
        setTimeout(check, 10);
    }
}    
check();
```

This is based on this Answer: [Set title in the window popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501424/set-title-in-the-window-popup)

Here is your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QRq2h/

Comment: thanks for your tryin , but it doesn't works for me , i want to set the browser title from <h2> of the popup content