# Can't write properties to IE's DispHTMLWindow2

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm working on a system that has a popup capability.

Currently I can't get it to work on IE.

Every other browser return a DOM Window element on `window.open` call, but IE returns a `DispHTMLWindow2` object, which doesn't work seamlessly.

For reading purposes, it's is working just fine, but when I need to modify information inside the popup, it doesn't work on IE.

I need to set the title of the popup window from the opener, what I'm doing like this:

```
popup.document.title = 'Some title';
```

This doesn't work. Neither setting a global property to the popup window works:

```
popup.someRandomProperty = 'foo';
```

Well, if it might be helpful, I'm doing this on a secure application, running over HTTPS.

### Edit: excerpt of the code that opens the window:

```
// Defining window specs
windowSpecs = "width="  + persistentWindowSettings.width  + "," +
              "height=" + persistentWindowSettings.height + "," +
              "top="    + persistentWindowSettings.top    + "," +
              "left="   + persistentWindowSettings.left   + "," +
              "status=0,"    +
              "location=no," +
              "resizable";

// A chat window has not yet been opened for this interaction, so we'll open a new one.
windowUrl = "popup_chat.php?interactionId=" + interactionId;
windowName = "";
popupChatWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, windowSpecs);
popupChatWindow.windowSlotId = persistentWindowSettings.slotId; // this doesn't work
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to pop the window. There are certain differences in what the browsers security model will allow. Also there is a timing issue in IE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501424/set-title-in-the-window-popup

Comment: Adding a delay won't help me at this case. Timer-based solutions are not fail proof. Since the system is kind of heavy, it's hard to know how much time it would take to load the page.