# Set tab title on javascript window.open to show PDF file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, pdf, window.open

I am ***opening a new tab to display a PDF file***. I have the PDF file data on a bytearray, base 64.

I am able to get the data, and display it doing this:

```
downloadFile(strData, name) {
    var newdata = "data:" + "application/pdf" + ";base64," + (strData);
    var newWindow = window.open(newdata, "_blank");
    newWindow.onload = function() { document.title = "My title"; }
return true;
}
```

The problem i am having is that i am ***not able to set the title to the new tab opened.***

I would like to set a title like "PDF File" or just the name of the document (i am getting the file data and the file name separately and passing it to my downloadFile function.

***Is there any way to set the title to this tab?*** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
  ....
  var newWindow = window.open(newdata, "_blank");
  newWindow.document.title = "Some title";
  ....
```

**EDIT:**

Another way to do this might be to send an iframe to a new window instead of opening it directly with the base64 string.

So something like:

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.write('<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + (strData) + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
newWindow.document.title = "Your Title Here";
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, this doesnt work. The title is still saying "data:"

Comment: @melli-182 Instead, you may try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501424/set-title-in-the-window-popup) answer.  It suggests using `setTimeout` to make sure the document is actually loaded before trying to set the title.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Unfortunately is still doesnt working. I am trying to reach a solution, i will update this as soon i get one. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @melli-182  I added one more suggestion that *may* work.

Comment: Perfect! This solution really helps! Thanks for your time and collaboration!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
var newWindow = window.open(newdata, "_blank");
setTimeout(function(){ newWindow.document.title = 'my new title'; }, 1000);
```