# How to set a file name using window.open in React

Tags: reactjs, window.open

I would like to open in React a PDF file in a new tab when the URL is

```
blob:http://localhost:300/sample.pdf
```

Currently, it opens PDF file in a new tab, but  the URL is

```
blob:http://localhost:3001/cfd3b31b-b4a8-4c65-aead-694fd27f12a8
```

My goal is to set the name to the pdf file in the URL (not download file)
What should be changed in the code in order to add the file name in the URL?

Code in React.js

```
 import axios from "axios";

const ShowPDF = () => {
    const getPdfFileAsBlob = async () => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5001/pdf`;

        //Force to receive data in a Blob Format
        const config: any = {
            responseType: "blob",
        };

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(url, config);

            //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
            const file = new Blob([response.data], {
                type: "application/pdf",
            });

            //Build a URL from the file
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            //Open the URL on new Window
            window.open(fileURL);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return <button onClick={getPdfFileAsBlob}>Show PDF</button>;
};

export default ShowPDF;
```

Code in Node.js - server.jsconst fs = require("fs");

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const excel = require("exceljs");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// GET
// Pdf route that will serve pdf
app.get("/pdf", (req, res) => {
    const file = fs.createReadStream("./public/samplePDF.pdf");
    file.pipe(res);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server Started on Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Hi hi, you can check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768595/set-tab-title-on-javascript-window-open-to-show-pdf-file