# window.URL.createObjectURL set filename to open pdf in new tab

Tags: javascript, url, window

I want to set a custom filename in createObjectURL of the blob. Right now, its showing something like this:

*<URL>/bfefe410-8d9c-4883-86c5-d76c50a24a1d*

```
const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
const pdfWindow = window.open();
pdfWindow.location.href = data;
```

I don't want to download the file (its solution is already present on StackOverflow), it should be open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing answers from [Set tab title on javascript window.open to show PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768595/set-tab-title-on-javascript-window-open-to-show-pdf-file) and [Set title in the window popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501424/set-title-in-the-window-popup), I tested with the following solutions which worked well on most browsers.

```
const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
const pdfWindow = window.open();
pdfWindow.location.href = data;

fileTitle = "hello-world.pdf";
// Set the window title
pdfWindow.document.title = fileTitle;

// Make sure that the window is loaded
pdfWindow.onload = () => {
    // And then add a timeout to guarentee the title is changed
    setTimeout(() => {
        newWindow.document.title = fileTitle;
    }, 500)
}
```