# Change a pop-up window's title using a Tampermonkey script?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

Is there a way to use Tampermonkey to change the window title for a pop-up (child?) window? (This is for a streaming audio player)

Usually, we would use `document.title` to change the browser page/tab title for a webpage, but in this case it doesn't work. I believe that is because it is a pop-up spawned by the main webpage.

Is there a way to accomplish this `via Tampermonkey`.

[**This is the site**](http://wibx950.com) with the pop-up I wish to modify. *Click the "Listen Now" red button at top right and the pop-up will. I wish to change the title for that pop-up window.*

---

References I tried/used:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/changing-the-title-on-a-popup-window/2294/2
- [Set title in the window popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501424/set-title-in-the-window-popup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the kind of popup given in your question, changing the title is simplicity itself.  Merely set the script to run on the URL of the popup and then use `document.title`

Here is a **complete working script** that operates on the "Listen Now" popup of [that page](http://wibx950.com/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Change popup title
// @match    *://wibx950.com/listen-live/popup/
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

document.title = "WKRP";
```

---

<sup>If you have a more intractable example, post a link/recipe to/for it.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You can open a new link to your own site with an iframe of your targeted site and change the title of your own site.

example normal html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>The title of your page</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://wibx950.com/"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Much less efficient than just setting `document.title`.